# Disable button during weekend + base on hours

Tags: javascript

I just give up doing this and need help because my brain finally stuck...

here is the situation

I want this button **[ Submit Form ]** to be disabled (not disappear) base on time, let say I want this button to work normally **every day start from 5:00 PM - 12:00 AM** but after that this button will be disabled and user cannot be clicking the button (the button just freeze) it also better with message saying that submit form only available during bussiness hour or so

this button also only work every day **except on the weekend** so that people cannot submit any form during the weekend (sat and Sunday)

the time is base on my current country time... emmm this is hard to explain, I mean.. like UTC +8 pacific time? because the user that submits this form base on my local time

if someone can help or willing to try.. it mean alot to me

update:
this is the closed script that I found that almost what I want except they do not disable the button during weekend

```
<input class="submit" type="submit" id="checktime" value="Check"/>

<script type="text/javascript" defer="defer">
<!-- 
var enableDisable = function(){
    var UTC_hours = new Date().getUTCHours() +1;
    if (UTC_hours > 17 && UTC_hours < 24){
        document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = false;
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById('checktime').disabled = true;
    }
};
setInterval(enableDisable, 1000*60);
enableDisable();
// -->
</script>
```

Credit this code I get from member stackoverflow : Marko from 2014

Comment: what have you tried so far? edit your question to include your code as formatted text

Comment: I think this check should be done server side. when the server render the page if possible, or be an API call.

Comment: I try with the existing code from many sources, I am not a programmer but still learning.. this task was giving from my boss and I really had no idea how to put something I have because it really near to fail

Answer (score 1):

Whatever you do, remember that you will have to check validity of submission time on the server side too. Disabling a button in the browser will not stop 'hackerish' users to submit the form/anything.

Otherwise the best what you can do is running a check periodically and enabling/disabling the button with that granularity (e.g. every 5 seconds or so).

```js
setInterval(function(){
   var now=new Date();
   document.getElementById("culprit").disabled=now.getSeconds()<30;
   document.getElementById("time").innerHTML=now.getSeconds();
},5000);
```

```html
<button id="culprit">Clicky</button>
<div id="time"></div>
```

This small demo checks if it is the first or the second half of the minute (that is already boring enough to wait for, even if it displays the time), for your real code you would need the more sophisticated test suggested in @StefanOctavian's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48825101/7916438):

```
var now = new Date()
document.getElementById("culprit").disabled=now.getDay() >= 5 || now.getHours() < 17;
```

Comment: thanks for helping, unfortunately .. I am little bit confuse

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this using only javascript, you can use the `Date` object like this: when the page loads, get the information about the current day and hour and disable the button if neccessary:

```
var now = new Date()
if(now.getDay() >= 5 // Saturday & Sunday
   || (now.getHours() >=  5 && now.getHours() < 12))
     button.disabled = true
```

Then, to enable it again when the clock steucks 12 AM, you could get the interval of time between `Date.now()` and `now.setHours(12)` and use `setTimeout` to reactivate the button then.

Comment: thank you for helping me, since I was not a programmer(just graphic designer) , how can I make this code to work? should I make index.html and also placing this code inside with javascript?

Comment: I just make like this ..https://notepad.pw/r25f1xus but.. the button still can be clicking

Comment: Hi, can you provide the html code for the button?. If not we cannot provide a working code to solve your problem

Comment: I just update my post with code, please review it :)

Comment: You need a simple ```now.getHours()<17``` for OP's weekday-schedule